# criteria.list() shows null pointer exception

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'am working on Hibernate 3.3. Recently I started using criteria. My Annotation class is as follows..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAG_ADMINLOGIN", schema = "EMAG_USER")
public class Adminlogin implements java.io.Serializable {

private String username;
private String password;
private String fullname;
private long isenabled;

@Id
@Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 40)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
@Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 40)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "FULLNAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getFullname() {
    return this.fullname;
}

public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}
@Column(name = "ISENABLED", precision = 0)
public long getIsenabled() {
    return this.isenabled;
}

public void setIsenabled(long isenabled) {
    this.isenabled = isenabled;
}
}
```

And my criteria code is as follows

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Adminlogin.class);
criteria=criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", "admin"));
List list=criteria.list();
```

this code showing error when isEnabled value is null on a row. I know it can not convert null value to primitive data type long. So I want to know is there any other way to skip null value of any property . (I posted one table class, and i have more tables with same kind of class mappings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change type of 'isenabled' to 'Long' or have default value defined for the column in db schema based on your requirements.

Comment: I already know i can do it. Here i posted one table annotated class. But I've lot more. If i change in annotation class i have to change my entire code...

Comment: Then mention what you know in your question. Other will know you changed/have lot of class which did not follow write some-test some.(' I've lot more')

Comment: I updated.. After the lots of searching changing to Long or BigDecimal object or some other object is the way to do it.. Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use the NotFound annotation:
may be your problem will be solved

```
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Comment: still i'm getting this 'Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter' error message...

Comment: Change the primitive long to Long class